# Google Maps - when map should show up sometimes "a is undefined" error occurs or map is blank. How to prevent?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, undefined

I'm getting some trouble with initializing my map and adding the circles an markers. Sometimes it works, sometimes I get a "TypeError: a is undefined" message and sometimes the map is just grey.

Here is a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/og5ecb0u/

HTML:

```
<div id="map" class="hidden"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var my_locations = [{"place":"M%FCnchen","place_id":"ChIJ2V-Mo_l1nkcRfZixfUq4DAE","radius":5000,"lat":48.1351253,"lng":11.581980599999952}],
  circle_option = {
        strokeColor: "#156fbd",
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: "#156fbd",
        fillOpacity: 0.35
    },
  markers = [],
  circles = [];
  function init_map(myLatLng){
    console.log(typeof google === 'object' && typeof google.maps === 'object'); 
    var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 5,
          center: myLatLng,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
          disableDefaultUI: true
        };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
    $('#map').removeClass('hidden');
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function(){
        var myLatLng = [],
            len = my_locations.length;
      for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                myLatLng[i]=new google.maps.LatLng(my_locations[i].lat,     my_locations[i].lng);
                markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatLng[i],
                    map: map,
                    icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png"
                });             
                circle_option.map = map;
                circle_option.radius = my_locations[i].radius;
                circle_option.lat = my_locations[i].lat;
                circle_option.lng = my_locations[i].lng;            
                circles[i]=new google.maps.Circle(circle_option);
                circles[i].bindTo('center', markers[i], 'position');

            }       

    });
  }

  function show_locations_from_object(){
        var center_of_map = new google.maps.LatLng(51.5167, 9.9167);        
        init_map(center_of_map);
    }
    show_locations_from_object();
});
```

CSS:

```
#map {
    float: left;
    width: 630px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    position: relative;     
}
```

Since I have the "tilesloaded" event listener I thought there shouldn't be any undefined error. What kind of check could solve the problem or what am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**
After Updating from Firefox version 40.0 to 44.0 the "a is undefined" error doesn't occure anymore. The blank map error doesn't reproduce in the fiddle anymore but in my original code which is a bit more complex.

Comment: Where exactly is `a` being defined in your code?

Comment: It's in the google maps script, not in mine. But I think I set all my maps parameter correctly, that's why I don't know where the error comes from.

Comment: I've reloaded the fiddle multiple times, I never got an error or a grey map.

Comment: Ah I see, Dr. Molle please try it in Firefox. It seems to work in Chrome.

Comment: I've tried in firefox too, no issues.

Comment: Oh ok, strange, but thanks for the input. With Version 40.0 I get the error...

Comment: Have you tried upgrading FireFox?  According to the [FAQ](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/browsersupport), the API supports: "The current and previous version of Firefox (Windows, Mac OS X, Linux)".   On my Windows PC I have FF43.0.4

Comment: Yes, I already did and updated the question. Thank you! The "a is undefined" error doesn't show up anymore, but there is still the grey, blank map bug which unfortunately isn't in the fiddle. But I'll try to find what causes that and keep you updated.

Answer (score -1):

I have read the comments and I think the problem for the grey map is that your API key is used to mutch but weird that it doesn't show in fiddle then.

hope this helps.